# MCF API metrics : why so few?

Tags: api, google-analytics

From the documentation of the MCF reporting API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/), I get that we can only get *totalConversions* and *totalConversionValues*.

Those 2 metrics are calculated as being the sum of transactions and goals for the first, the later being the sum of transaction values and goal values.

I have absolutely no use in those metrics since I have 15+ goals setup in most of my accounts. I want to use only transaction completions (orders) and value (e-commerce revenue) as metrics to analyse MCF paths.

Is there a way to do this with the MCF API ?
If not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

Turns out you have to use a filter for that. By setting a filter like "mcf:conversionType==Transaction" you can effectively only query on transactions and leave goals alone.